# How to set a new taxonomy term without overwriting an existing one when using Rules?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, users

I'm using the Rules Action **`Set Data Value`** to set a taxonomy term for a specific user (uid= 75). The tag field exists in the user entity, and is set to "Unlimited".

There's nothing complicated about the rule, which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_invited_user" : {
    "LABEL" : "Invited user",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "user_presave" ],
    "IF" : [ { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "account:uid" ], "value" : "75" } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "account:field-user-tag" ], "value" : "27608" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can set the term, but if there's another term set already for that user, it's overwritten.

***How can I set a new term without overwriting an existing one?***

Answer (score 2):

The Rules Action **Set a data value** that your Rule uses, can only set 1 value, while you're trying to update something that is a list (or to use your own words: "*...  set a new term without overwriting an existing one*").

So try to replace your Rules Action (ie with the `data_set`) with an action "**Add an item to a list**". When doing so, you probably also want to set "ENFORCE UNIQUENESS" to `true`, so that you "*only add the item to the list if it is not yet contained*". Even though for your case it may not make a difference, IMO that is a kind of safety-belt when using this action.

For way more details about this, refer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)". While reviewing this, also pay attention to the "Fetch entity by ID" (within the Rules loop): I wouldn't be surprised if you'd also need to add a similar "Fetch entity by ID".

Ps: I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...